# Coinbase API: How to get spot-prices of all supported coins

Tags: coinbase-api

Is there an API for getting all spot-prices of supported with just one call ?

For now, it seems possible only for each currency pair e.g.) BTC-USD

However, I've found the following API to support it but it's **not officially listed** on the developer site

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/usd/spot

Can I use this API for getting all price data of all supported coins ?

Thanks

Comment: the spot endpoint is documented here: https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-prices#get-spot-price

Answer (score 4):

I believe the only way to get the prices for all coins in a single request is to use the exchange-rates endpoint but it gets more than what coinbase trades and since this tells you how much you can get for 1 USD, you have to do the `1/rate` math to get the price.

for example

```
1 ATOM = 1 / 0.04149635869452455 = $24.0985
```

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD

```
{
"data": {
"currency": "USD",
"rates": {
  "AED": "3.672973",
  "AFN": "97.372693",
  "ALL": "107.034241",
  "AMD": "490.957033",
  "ANG": "1.803208",
  "AOA": "564",
  "ARS": "101.5085",
  "AUD": "1.399191",
  "AWG": "1.8",
  "AZN": "1.700805",
  "BAM": "1.729247",
  "BBD": "2",
  "BDT": "85.824273",
  "BGN": "1.72742",
  "BHD": "0.377048",
  "BIF": "1994.142167",
  "BMD": "1",
  "BND": "1.366618",
  "BOB": "6.898625",
  "BRL": "5.552737",
  "BSD": "1",
  "BTN": "75.524027",
  "BWP": "11.716473",
  "BYN": "2.536338",
  ...
  }}}
```

Otherwise you'd probably need to get all the products and get the ticker price for each product but you'd have to throttle it so you don't make to many requests per second.

loop the results from

https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products

and use

[https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/{product_id}/ticker](https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/%7Bproduct_id%7D/ticker)

to get the price.